# How to get a SQLite database name in python

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

Is there a way I can get a SQLite database name in Python.

I am using the following code to get the database name:

```
con=sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("PRAGMA database_list;")
curr_table = cursor.fetchall()
```

But the output I get is:

```
[(0, u'main', u'')]
```

When I should be getting something like

```
[(0,u'main',u'/Users/testdb.db'),                           
(2,u'test',u'/Users/testdb.db')]
```

Comment: what? ... I dont understand the question ... sqlite has a filename(or in :memory) as the database name ... do you mean get the table names?

Comment: I used this code con=sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("PRAGMA database_list;") But it's not listing the correct databases

Comment: what do you mean? what does it list and what do you expect? ... this is not a reproduceable example as it stands ...

Comment: I've modified the question. Hope it is better

Comment: Those databases are not associated with your connection that is using `:memory:` so you won't see them. Read the docs: https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_database_list

Comment: Got it, So is there a workaround?

Comment: Yes - connect to the file that contains the databases.

Answer (score 3):

You should be connecting to the actual file - otherwise you cannot view the databases within it.

So, you just need to change your code to this:

```
con=sqlite3.connect('/Users/testdb.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("PRAGMA database_list;")
curr_table = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: But this won't give all the databases it's just giving me the output as:[(0, u'main', u'/Users/testdb.db')]

Comment: @anonymous - You can only see the databases within the file that you are connected to. SQLite is a file-based database, so you aren't connecting to a server at all. Is your file `testdb.db` an actual SQLite database file?

Comment: If you only see one database, that is because there is only one.